# Where can I learn how to style an ASP.NET WebParts page?

Tags: asp.net, css, web-parts

I'm trying to style a custom WebParts portal page I'm working on, but I'm lost on how to style it.  Are there any resources out there that show how to style the WebPartZone, the PageCatalogZone, and the WebParts themselves?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are a rather good resource for the purpose:

http://joostschermers.net/post/Styling-WebParts-%28Part1%29.aspx

http://joostschermers.net/post/Styling-WebParts-%28Part-2%29.aspx

Comment: The links are dead. But I think if you just can also just go to: http://joostschermers.net/